# Strategies to manage long-term course development

Tags: course-design

I'm in an interesting position in that I get to work with multiple instructors on multiple courses.  I'm usually tasked with coming up with draft assignments, rubrics, and other learning material.  So far I've been approaching this on a basis of "oh, the instructor asked for X, so I'll do X".   Each new project is essentially its own thing.  However, I'm noticing that:

a) my colleagues do the same thing, so we are all the curators of huge, generally unorganized and possibly duplicate databases of course material
b) I basically forget about a piece of material once I send it to the instructor.  There's not continuity, evaluation, or improvement.  If the instructor has feedback, I'll incorporate it at a later date, but I myself am not really spending the time to generate a plan for continual improvement of the learning material.

What are some strategies for managing this type of development over multiple courses and multiple semesters so that I can maintain, upgrade, and evaluate my learning material without spending so much time in administration that I can't develop anything new?

Comment: I think the problem is inherent to the nature of the work you're doing.  If you had responsibility for specific courses, then you'd be naturally motivated to keep these materials organized, and to go through them from time to time to make improvements and fill gaps. Alternatively, you could start thinking about which items would, together, form the basis for a good book or website.